# Wordpress post page not showing all images in gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am hoping someone can assist, as this is killing me. I'm working with someone elses code and having lots of trouble and I'm only new at wordpress.

What I want to acheive is for the post to display the first image from the gallery at the top of the page, then the second image below it (next to some text content), then under that I want it to display all the remaining images in the gallery. For some reason, it's currently leaving the last two images in the gallery out, as though they are being intentionally excluded. Thanks so much for your help I appreciate it.

This is the current code:

```
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) {
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $images = GetPostImages(); // Get Post Images
    $tags = GetPostTags(); // Get Post Tags String
    ?>                    
<div class="project">

<img src="<?php echo $images[1]->guid; ?>" class="large" width="1000" height="700" />

<div class="projectdesc">  
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p class="tags"><?php echo $tags; ?></p>

    <?php 
the_content(); ?>

</div>

<img src="<?php echo $images[2]->guid; ?>" class="right" width="600" height="400" />

 <?php
        // Additional Project Images
        for ($i = 3; $i < count($images); $i++) {
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $images[$i]->guid; ?>" class="large" width="1000"/>        
            <?php
        }
        ?> 

    </div>

    <?php
}
}

get_footer();
?>`
```

The code in the functions.php file is also below. I think this controls the way the post page processes images?

```
function GetPostImages() {
global $post;

// Get image attachments
$images = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID);

// Sort by menu_order
foreach ($images as $key=>$image) {
    $newImages[$image->menu_order] = $image;
}

// Return
return $newImages;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

use **wp_get_attachment_image_src()** to get the image source

```
$attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(int $id,string $size); //where $id is image post id

$width  =  $attr[1];
$height =  $attr[2];
$src    =  $attr[0]; //the source

echo sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" height="%s" width="%s"/>',$src,$height,$width);
```

witin the functions.php file or an include file within the functions.php include...

```
function setup_images(){

//Register Image dimensions
add_image_size( 'large',1000,700,true); //'large' will be the string used in $size
add_image_size( 'med',600,400,true);  //or 'med'
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','setup_images'); //hook that function up in the right place
```

Comment: So do I just replace the old code with the sample you provided? What happens to those first to references to the large and small image? There is actually some content between the small image and all the other below it that I left out in the code sample to keep it simple. Sorry I'm not too experienced with wordpress just yet.

Comment: Also, is there a simpler approach. For example I can see the second image can be referenced using: $images[2]

Is there a way to make this a range? i.e.. $images[2-100]

Comment: provide me with the full script of the page, and an example of what you are looking to achieve for me to further help you

Comment: Ok thanks so much @user622018. I have edited my original question with the full code.